# Overlay <A> with semi-transparent PNG

Tags: jquery, css

I have lots of anchor tags that each contain a thumbnail image:

```
<a href="..." class="movie_poster_item" id="movie_poster_item_6">
    <img src="..." height="267">
</a>
```

I want to overlay this semi-transparent image (poster-info-overlay.png) on top of the thumbnail (inside the anchor tag):

[image]

But I'm not sure which method to use; append(), before() or after(). Can somebody please advise on the correct method? I obviously need to set the z-index somehow too, depending on which method I'm using.

This is my jQuery code so far:

```
$('a.movie_poster_item').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this)...
});
```

Comment: `$(this).append('<img src="poster-info-overlay.png">');` will place it after the image that is already there, and if you set the position right, it will be on top of the existing image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd just have:

```
<a href="..." class="movie_poster_item" id="movie_poster_item_6">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="..." height="267">
</a>
```

Then for the js:

```
$('.movie_poster_item').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.overlay').show();
},
function() {
  $(this).find('.overlay').hide();
};
```

just make sure the z-index for the overlay is higher than the img, eg:

```
.movie_poster_item .overlay { position: absolute; z-index: 2; }
.movie_poster_item img { position: relative/absolute; z-index: 1; }
```

Comment: The JS is really kind of pointless with this example. Ditch it and use CSS. Ex: a .overlay { display: none; } a:hover .overlay {display: block; } You also won't need to adjust the position or z-index of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your semi-transparent image as the background of the a tag like this:

```
$(this).css('background','url(poster-info-overlay.png) 0px 0px no-repeat');
```